# How can I convert IO ByteString to IO String

Tags: haskell

I know how to convert a ByteString to a String with unpack but I'm struggling to figure out how to convert an IO ByteString (which is what I get back from the fetchHeader function in HaskellNet) to an IO String. I'm basically trying to do something like this

```
getAllHeadersForMessageUID :: IMapConnection -> UID -> IO String
getAllHeadersForMessageUID connection uid = do
   headers <- fetchHeader connection uid  
   return (headers  >>= BS.unpack)
```

The error message doesn't make sense to me

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[BS.ByteString]’
            with actual type ‘BS.ByteString’
In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘headers’
In the first argument of ‘return’, namely ‘(headers >>= BS.unpack)
```

I don't know why a list of ByteString is expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `return $ BS.unpack headers` instead of `return (headers >>= BS.unpack)`.

Or try `return $ map BS.unpack headers` if headers is a list of ByteStrings.

Besides the fact that it happens to type check (and I'm assuming `BS.unpack headers` works), here's a way to think about things:

- `headers` is a pure value
- `BS.unpack` is a pure function
- `headers >>= ...` doesn't make sense because the LHS of `>>=` needs to be a monadic computation
- `... >>= BS.unpack` doesn't make sense because the RHS of `>>=` needs to be a function which produces a monadic computation
- `BS.unpack headers` is the string we want to return, but it's a pure value
- we therefore use `return` to promote the pure value to a monadic computation

*Update:*

The following code shows that if `fetchHeader` has type `IO [BS.ByteString]`, then your code will type check:

```
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

fetchHeader :: IO [BS.ByteString]   -- this works
-- fetchHeader :: IO BS.ByteString  -- this doesn't
fetchHeader = undefined

foo :: IO String
foo = do
  headers <- fetchHeader
  return $ headers >>= BS.unpack
```

On the other hand, if you change its type to `IO BS.ByteString` you get the error you encountered.

*Update 2*:

Interestingly enough, when `headers` is a list of ByteStrings, the expression `headers >>= BS.unpack` does make sense and is equivalent to:

```
concat $ map BS.unpack headers
```

Comment: Yes, that worked (the "headers" is a single ByteString) but I still don't understand the error message --- why did it want an array of ByteStrings?

Comment: By the way, thanks for having answered so quickly. Really appreciated by this struggling novice!

Comment: @David It is expecting the list `Monad` instance for that call to `(>>=)` because the expression `(headers  >>= BS.unpack)` must give a list (in this case `String` since `String` is a synonym for `[Char]`). Also, this is a list not an array.

Comment: Got it and understood. Thanks. I did mean to say list rather than array though :-)

Answer (score 0):

User5402's answer assumes the ByteString is pure ASCII (which is OK if you are the only person using your code, but there are several reasons why it's a bad idea if you intend to share it)
If the ByteString is encoded with UTF-8: you can convert it to String like this:

```
import qualified Codec.Binary.UTF8.String as UTF8
foo b = do
  bs <- b
  return $ UTF8.decode $ unpack bs
```

I'm not sure how to deal with other encodings such as windows codepages (other than by setting the encoding of a handle, which isn't applicable here).